# No internet connection after ubuntu server 20.04 install, ifconfig not available

Tags: networking, server, internet, 20.04

I recently installed Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS on my desktop, and found out there was no internet connection even though I had the LAN cable connected. `ifconfig` and `iwconfig` failed saying the corresponding packages `net-tools` and `wireless-tools` were not installed.

**EDIT**

Here is the info requested. Please find the image [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31JYh.jpg)

Comment: Add to your question above the complete output of `ip addr`

Comment: Also `ip link`. Look at `service NetworkManager status`, to. The whole `ifconfig/ifup/ifdown` system is depreciated in later Ubuntu releases.

Comment: @waltinator Network Manager is not installed by default in Ubuntu server.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Along with @chili555 request, also please show us `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces`.

Comment: I have added the requested info. Please take a look.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Networking in Ubuntu server is managed by netplan. Your file lacks the details needed to connect the ethernet properly.

First, let's rename the file:

```
sudo mv /etc/netplan/*.yaml  /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
```

Now, let's change it to include the required details:

```
sudo nano /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
```

Change the file to read:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens33:
      dhcp4: true
```

Netplan is very particular about spacing, indentation, etc. Proofread carefully twice. Save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and exit (Ctrl+x) the text editor. Follow with:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

You should be all set.

Comment: Good job! +1... however, be careful with your mv, as there may be more than one .yaml file in /etc/netplan.

Comment: worked. Thank you :)

Comment: @heynnema Let's discuss, please: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107486/heynnema-and-chili555-discuss-netplan

Comment: solved my problem on ubuntu-desktop. but why `netplan` is not installed on ubuntu desktop already? I had to download `.deb` file. ***thank you***

Comment: I was hoping I would find an answer here, but alas, I didn't. My netplan config is there. Did 20+ servers all the same. This one, however, no dice. Fresh server out of the box too. Log during install says it can't resolve archive.ubuntu.com to download packages.

Answer (score 2):

A short addon to chili555's answer: In my case, the only problem was that for some strange reason, Ubuntu believed my network interface name in `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` to be `enp0s5` instead of `enp0s4` which was the correct for my VM.

Comment: You can find out the name of your network interface name using `ifconfig`

Comment: @RyanQuey As per question statement (and I can confirm) `ifconfig` is not installed, and it cannot be without network.

Comment: @RyanQuey You have to have it installed first. Can't install if you have no network!

Comment: Since ifconfig is not available you can also use the command `ip link`