# Ubuntu 20.10 server network is not starting on boot

Tags: networking

I have just installed 20.10 server and I am unable to get the network to start on bootup. If I issue sudo dhclient eno1 the network starts successfully but I have to do this after every reboot.

/etc/network/interfaces:

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eno1
iface eno1 inet dhcp

I've tried changing the order of this and also putting auto on one line with no success.

This is the output from cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml

#This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:

ethernets: {}

version: 2

Comment: The `/etc/network/interfaces` method is deprecated; that is, obsolete, in Ubuntu 17.10 and later. Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions from the duplicate post listed above and it resolved my issue.
[No internet connection after ubuntu server 20.04 install, ifconfig not available](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233934/no-internet-connection-after-ubuntu-server-20-04-install-ifconfig-not-available/1233997#1233997)

Thanks for everyone's help.

Steve