# UpUbuntu 20.04.2 LTS Wifi Network / Ethernet connected but no internet

Tags: networking, 20.04, internet, dns

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS being a previous windows user. However, now I have the issue that neither Ethernet nor other WiFi connections let me access the internet. Other devices around me connect with no troubles.
I have followed several other suggestions like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233934/no-internet-connection-after-ubuntu-server-20-04-install-ifconfig-not-available) but without success.

`ping 8.8.8.8` yields
`PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data`

and

`ping www.google.com` yields `Temporary failure in name resolution`

I am not sure what other information to provide and would appreciate any suggestions.

Update:
I came across [this forum](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2330148), where it was suggested to run the following commands:

`sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf`

`sudo echo 'nameserver 8.8.8.8' | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf`

After running this, the internet connection begins to work. However, if I reboot the computer then I have to do it all over again.

As requested by @chili555, the output of `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` is :

`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 19 Jul  7 17:36 /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: @nbob. Can you post the output of "ifconfig -a"? and also how are you connected to internet (hardware)?

Comment: @jpbrain itconfig is not found and I also cannot install it because no internet connection. I have tried both Ethernet cable and several wifi connections to connect

Comment: @waltinator sorry I am not sure how to interpret that output

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of: `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf`  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

The file resolv.conf is incorrect. Please do:

```
sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf
sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

Now check:

```
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

If you get ping returns, you're all set.

Comment: I followed the two commands, however ```ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com``` still returns "Temporary failure in name resolution"

Comment: How about: `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` ?

Comment: That yields ```PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data```

Comment: Please reboot and try again: `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` and: `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: I rebooted then did ```sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf``` then ```sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf```. The output from ```ls -al /etc/resolv.conf``` is ```lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Jul  8 21:49 /etc/resolv.conf -> /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf```. ping -c3 8.8.8.8 shows ```PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=117 time=18.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=117 time=16.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=117 time=16.1 ms``` and ```ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com``` gives temporary failure in name resolution

Comment: We have made some progress. You are connected to the internet but still cannont resolve names to numbers. Are there any settings in Network Manager that relate to DNS? https://www.liberiangeek.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/google_dns_provider_1_thumb.png

Comment: When checking IPv4 or IPv6 in the current internet connection, they are both set to just "Automatic" and the DNS fields are empty.