# DNS resolution broken after upgrading Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04

Tags: networking, server, 22.04, dns, display-resolution

After upgrading a server from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04, the DNS name resolution does not work anymore. `ping 8.8.8.8` works but `ping google.com` returns `ping: google.com: Name or service not known`. Also wget does not work and `sudo apt update` cannot resolve:

```
~$ sudo apt update
Ign:1 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:1 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:1 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Err:1 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  Could not resolve 'de.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
  Could not resolve 'de.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
  Could not resolve 'de.archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  Could not resolve 'de.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease  Could not resolve 'de.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease  Could not resolve 'de.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I tried to use `8.8.8.8` as nameserver in `/etc/resolv.conf`. In this case, `ping google.com` returns `ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution`.

Only if I run `sudo dhclient eth0`, everything works fine. However, only until the next reboot of the machine.

Here is some more information about the system, probably it may be helpful:

```
~$ ls -la /etc/resolv.conf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 340 Jan 27 21:08 /etc/resolv.conf
```

---

```
~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
search DOMAINS
```

---

```
~$ resolvectl
Global
       Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
resolv.conf mode: foreign
      DNS Domain: DOMAINS

Link 2 (eth0)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 3 (eth1)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 4 (docker0)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
```

---

```
~$ sudo service systemd-resolved status
○ systemd-resolved.service - Network Name Resolution
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:systemd-resolved.service(8)
             man:org.freedesktop.resolve1(5)
             https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-network-configuration-managers
             https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-resolver-clients
```

---

```
~$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

---

Any thoughts how this can be fixed? I have been trying for hours without success.

Comment: Please start here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1350548/upubuntu-20-04-2-lts-wifi-network-ethernet-connected-but-no-internet/1350576#1350576 Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf` resolved the issue.
(See [here](https://github.com/pop-os/pop/issues/773)).