# No Internet even though Wifi or Ethernet is connected, Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: wireless, internet, ethernet

This problem with wifi or Ethernet connected but Internet going out is recent and seems to be happening after restarting, then, inexplicably after some length of time (hours), it starts working again.
This box is a Dell Precision T1700 w/16GB ram. Internet OK on all other devices (MS Win, Apple Mac, Android & iPhone) on same wifi network.

In upper right of screen the wifi or wired icons have a "?" overlaid.
Unplugged/reconnected gateway unit -> no change.
Any suggestions?

Here is some hardware info:

```
PCI Devices:
sudo lspci -nn
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller [8086:0c00] (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller [8086:0c01] (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0412] (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller [8086:0c0c] (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI [8086:8c31] (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:8c3a] (rev 04)
00:16.3 Serial controller [0700]: Intel 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family KT Controller [8086:8c3d] (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Ethernet Connection I217-LM [8086:153a] (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 [8086:8c2d] (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller [8086:8c20] (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 [8086:8c10] (rev d4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5 [8086:8c18] (rev d4)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 [8086:8c26] (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel C226 Series Chipset Family Server Advanced SKU LPC Controller [8086:8c56] (rev 04)
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller [0104]: Intel SATA Controller [RAID mode] [8086:2822] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:8c22] (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]:[AMD/ATI] Cape Verde GL [FirePro W4100] [1002:682c]
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: [AMD/ATI] Oland/Hainan/Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7000 Series] [1002:aab0]
```

Connected USB devices:

```
sudo lsusb
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0846:9053 NetGear, Inc. A6210
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver ← External Wifi reciever
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0781:5150 SanDisk Corp. SDCZ2 Cruzer Mini Flash Drive (thin)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0781:5581 SanDisk Corp. Ultra
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Network cards:

```
sudo lshw -class network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection I217-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 04
       serial: 64:00:6a:6f:ef:bf
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.15.0-58-generic firmware=0.13-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:29 memory:f7d00000-f7d1ffff memory:f7d3d000-f7d3dfff ioport:f080(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 5
       bus info: usb@2:1.5
       logical name: wlx3c37861ae5b6
       serial: 3c:37:86:1a:e5:b6
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=mt76x2u driverversion=5.15.0-58-generic firmware=0.0.00-b1 ip=192.168.12.230 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
<-- Orig.--
-- Edited -->
Upon request by @chili555, the following ping & ls command results have been added...
1st - ping -c3 8.8.8.8, 2nd - ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com, 3rd - ls -al /etc/resolv.conf. Also, the wifi is currently functioning.
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/esl8R.png
Note: The ping results shown were performed after the Internet started working. When connected with the Internet not working the ping on www.ubuntu.com fails.
```

Comment: Please edit your questtion to show the result of these terminal commands: `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` also: `ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com` and finally: `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Open a terminal and type `lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network` then edit your question above just adding the last 2 lines "Kernel driver in use:" and "Kernel modules:" please.

Comment: @darth_epoxy His wifi device is USB, not PCI and the driver is clearly mt76x2u.

Comment: Please clarify. Is it the wifi that doesn't work properly or the ethernet? If ethernet, please add: `sudo dmesg | grep -e e100 -e eno1`

Comment: @chili555, It was the wifi. But, at present it is actually working. My only hope for now would be that there might be a suggestion that might be of use if and when it happens again. Ultimately, I intend to wire it permanently. Just not quite there yet. Thanks for at least your willingness to assist.

Comment: @chili555 It's doing it again now. This time both w/wifi and wired. The ping 8.8.8.8 command produces essentially the same result as when internet is working except a little faster wired. However, the ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com command returns "ping: www.ubuntu.com: Temporary failure in name resolution. I presume this just verifies that there is a connection but that something is preventing the internet. Firewall? Port?

Comment: Please check here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1350548/upubuntu-20-04-2-lts-wifi-network-ethernet-connected-but-no-internet/1350576#1350576

Comment: @chili555 I did the commands you suggested to nBob and it appears to be working now. Thanks!
For general interest, those commands were: <sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf> and <sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf>.
Also, I did the commands that nBob reported in the update w/in his original post that partially worked for him. They were: sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf & sudo echo 'nameserver 8.8.8.8' | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf. These also seemed to work for me, even after restart.

Comment: @chili555 Unfortunately, after an Ubuntu update and required restart, the Internet (through both wifi & ethernet) was again lost. This time, your suggested fix did not seem to work (perhaps I could have waited longer?), however the nBob update solution did, and kept working after another restart. Not sure what to make of it all but it's quite annoying that the Internet cut out after the update and restart in the first place. Any comments?