# No Internet Ethernet is connected, Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: internet, ethernet, connection

I am experiencing a very similar issue to the following:

[No Internet even though Wifi or Ethernet is connected, Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1452383/no-internet-even-though-wifi-or-ethernet-is-connected-ubuntu-22-04)

The setup is a "Dell T5810 Precision Tower Desktop - (Black) (Intel Xeon E5-1650V4 3.60 GHz, 16 GB RAM, 512 GB SSD, NVIDIA Quadro M2000 Graphics, Windows 10 Pro)".

I added a new partition for Dual Boot and installed the Desktop Version of Ubuntu 22.04.

After first installation, under Network Settings - the Wired Connection always shows "Connecting" and never connected. I switched back to Windows and there is no issue with the internet connection. Therefore this is not a hardware issue.

Switching back to Ubuntu:

I reinstalled using the same PC Name as the Windows installation.

Auto DCHP always shows Connecting status.

I changed the DCHP to manual and used the same address as the Windows uses.

The status shows Connected with Manual DCHP - but doesn't connect to the internet.

If I disconnect the cable from the Router - Ubuntu tells me the cable has been disconnected.

The Wifi router never shows the server connected when running Ubuntu.

I also tried manual DNS - but given the fact the router doesn't detect the Ubuntu connection as having connected I'm not surprised this didn't work.

I've tried:

sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf

sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf

No luck.

The results from:

sudo lshw -class network

```
  *-network                
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection I217-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: enp0s25
       version: 05
       serial: 64:00:XX:XX:bf:a8 <-- Obscured
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.19.0-32-generic duplex=full firmware=0.13-4 ip=192.168.1.101 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:35 memory:f7200000-f721ffff memory:f7239000-f7239fff ioport:f020(size=32)
```

ping -c3 8.8.8.8

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.101 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.101 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.101 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 2051ms
pipe 3
```

ping -c3 [www.ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com)

```
ping: www.ubuntu.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

ls -al /etc/resolv.conf

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Mar 28 08:55 /etc/resolv.conf -> /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf
```

lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network

```
Blank

"Kernel driver in use:"

"Kernel modules:"
```

sudo dmesg | grep -e e100 -e enp0s25

```
[    0.967585] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver
[    0.967586] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
[    0.968063] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[    1.047973] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 0000:00:19.0 (uninitialized): registered PHC clock
[    1.120441] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) 64:00:XX:XX:bf:a8 <- Obscured
[    1.120448] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    1.120488] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: MAC: 11, PHY: 12, PBA No: FFFFFF-0FF
[    1.340578] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 enp0s25: renamed from eth0
[    7.435253] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 enp0s25: NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
[    7.435306] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp0s25: link becomes ready
```

---

I ordered a USB to Ethernet adaptor and this works. Does anyone has any suggestions on how to fix the issue with the PCI installed Ethernet adapter?

Comment: What kernel version are you using?